# Reattaching limbs with Heal or Profession (Surgeon)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, healing

I seem to remember somewhere that with a high enough Heal or Profession Surgeon skill that you could reattach someone's lost limb.

For example, Fighter gets his arm/hand cut off, Cleric (without using magic) makes the appropriate Heal/Profession (Surgeon) check, and the limb is reattached, but not usable for a certain amount of time.

Could someone give me a link or a reference in the right direction to where I can find these specific rules?

This could have come from 2nd or 3rd party materials, I don't remember where I got the idea from anymore.

Answer (score 2):

From Paizo itself there is nothing mundane linked with heal skill that can reattach lost limbs, or at least i never seen something like that related to this skill:

[Heal Skill](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/heal/)

Anyway keep in mind that there is nothing in the rules that can severe your arms or legs (not in combat at least). Usually these are houserules or GM's decisions related with campaign or character story.
Maybe there is something really specific that can cause your character a lost limb but I'm pretty sure is a magical meaning and not a mundane one; in the same way to reattach a lost limb, you need magic (regeneration for example).

Ofcourse, if you want, nothing can stop you to insert something like "Reattach Limbs" in the heal skill and give this ability a 30 DC or something like that.

> Homerule:
>
> **Reattach Limbs** DC 30 (hand/foot) DC 35 (arm) 40 (leg)
>
> Thanks to your surgery expertise you are capable of reattach lost
>   limbs. To reattach someone limbs, the limb can not be severed for more
>   than an hour before the surgical operation begins and you must be
>   trained in the heal skill. The operation take 4 hours for a hand or
>   foot and 8 hours for an arm or leg and you can't operate alone but
>   only with, at least, one support trained in the heal skill. The character who undergoes the surgical practice must succed a fortitude check at the end of the surgery equal to 15 (hand/foot) | 20 (arm) | 25  (leg). If the character fails the fortitude check he dies from blood loss.